# Can I Make My Entire Game World In blender?

Tags: modeling, unity

I was learning unity but decided to take a few months off to learn blender so I can make my own game assets. I was wondering if it would be a good idea to make all my assets in blender?, like can I make my entire world in blender then import it to unity or should I only make some and create the rest in unity ? I'm new to game development so I don't know what's the best practice. I feel like I'm asking a stupid question but any advise would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would say that the modern convention is to make 3D assets in _some_ kind of 3D modelling software and then export it to your game engine of choice. Many game engines only support modelling with primitives using only simple transforms (moving, scaling, etc...) and may also use _constructive solid geometry_ (A.K.A boolean operations). These are handy for prototyping or "blocking out" a game world, but are generally rather limited, and you will get much better results importing meshes from a 3D modelling program - just don't import it all as one piece!

Comment: if you like/love Blender and use all of its tools and don't want to mess around with import/export problems you might have a look at UPBGE ....the game engine "within" Blender. Here you can use all advantages of Blender...

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Can I import all in one piece if im using an SDD ? I just want to be able to make a whole world with my assets in it and import it straight to unity. Tell me why I shouldn't, if you don't mind explaining

Comment: @Chris i've watched videos on youtube about it, and it looks pretty crappy so I'm not too sure.

Comment: @YuriMckoy: Well...then you watched the wrong videos and didn't look what the pro's did with Blender....I don't say UPBGE is better than Unity...don't misunderstand that. I just said, that you don't have to mess around with import/export.